Firestore database: problem with date format
I am quite new to firestore, so my question might be very obvious.
I try to add data to firestore as follows:
try {
        await setDoc(doc(db, "appointments", id), data, {
            merge: true,
        }).then(handleSuccess());
    } catch (e) {
        handleError(e);
    }

and my data (which comes from scheduler) is as follows:
Object { title: "data", startDate: Date Sat Aug 10 2024 13:30:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time), endDate: Date Sat Aug 10 2024 14:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time), allDay: false, notes: "data" }

It works perfectly.
However, after reading some more docs, I realized that perhaps I should rather convert date to firebase date format. Then I developed a converting function and now what I add looks like this:
Object { title: "fff", startDate: {…}, endDate: {…}, allDay: false, notes: "fff", exDate: undefined }
​
allDay: false
​
endDate: Object { seconds: 1722942000, nanoseconds: 0 }
​
exDate: undefined
​
notes: "fff"
​
startDate: Object { seconds: 1722940200, nanoseconds: 0 }
​
title: "fff"

And this does not work (does not add items). I suspected that that is because one can not mix types in one collection, but not, even when removed all the records from collection, and try to add—it simply does not.
Let me know whether my understanding is false. Should I use working format and not care about the rest?

Firestore does not care about the type of field that you add to a document. Fields can contain any valid data and there does not need to be consistency between the fields in documents.  Please edit the question to show all the relevant code that doesn't work the way you expect.  We should be able to reproduce the behavior using everything you provide.

Please edit your question and add the information Doug asked for, and please also respond using @.

I believe the problem you're encountering can be attributed to the fact that there is a discrepancy between your date formatting. The startDate and endDate in your second object are formatted right, but the startDate and endDate from the scheduler data are still regular Date objects, causing an incompatibility.
Modify your data coming from the scheduler to convert Date objects to Timestamp before storing them in Firestore. It would look something like this:


const firestoreData = {
    title: data.title,
    startDate: Timestamp.fromDate(data.startDate),
    endDate: Timestamp.fromDate(data.endDate),
    allDay: data.allDay,
    notes: data.notes,
};

try {
    await setDoc(doc(db, "appointments", id), firestoreData, {
        merge: true,
    });
} catch (e) {
    handleError(e);
}



